# java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds

Tags: java

i like to get the duration between to datetime values in minutes.

```
public long datetimeDiffInMinutes(String dateStop, String dateStart) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDate firstDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStart, formatter);
        LocalDate secondDate = LocalDate.parse(dateStop, formatter);
        Duration d1 = Duration.between(firstDate, secondDate);
        long min = d1.toMinutes();
        
        return min;
    }
```

There will be thrown an exception: java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds

But i dont use "Seconds" in this function. This line throws the exception: Duration d1 = Duration.between(firstDate, secondDate);

Comment: Beware: Calculating elapsed time using only date & time-of-day may produce incorrect if your situation implies a time zone. Because of changes to the rules of a time zone, days vary in length, some shorter or longer than 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

You specify your dates with time information. That makes `LocalDate` a suboptimal choice. `LocalDateTime` is a better option. That already lets you create a duration.

Results may be off because of DST. Adding the right time zone should solve that:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // or an explicit one
ZonedDateTime firstDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStart, formatter).atZone(zone);
ZonedDateTime secondDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStop, formatter).atZone(zone);
Duration d1 = Duration.between(firstDateTime, secondDateTime);
long min = d1.toMinutes();
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the method you're calling ([`Duration.between(Temporal, Temporal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal))) states:

> The specified temporal objects must support the `SECONDS` unit. For full accuracy, either the `NANOS` unit or the `NANO_OF_SECOND` field should be supported.

But [`LocalDate.isSupported`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isSupported(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) is documented with:

> If the unit is a ChronoUnit then the query is implemented here. The supported units are: DAYS, WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS, DECADES, CENTURIES, MILLENNIA, ERAS
>
> All other ChronoUnit instances will return false.

So no, `LocalDate` doesn't support seconds, which is required for the method you're calling.

It may be worth considering that a `Duration` is intended to be an *elapsed* time - a fixed number of seconds etc. The elapsed time between two dates may depend on the time zone involved - because a day doesn't always have 24 hours when there are time zones involved.

If you're happy *assuming* a 24-hour day, you could use `Duration.ofDays(DAYS.between(firstDate, secondDate))`.

Answer (score 1):

For differences between *dates,* `Period` is a better representation.

Because your format string contains time, however, it looks like you want to be parsing to `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`. This way, the minutes (and seconds) you care about are not discarded:

```java
private static final DateTimeFormatter parser = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public long datetimeDiffInMinutes(String dateStop, String dateStart) {
    LocalDateTime firstDate = parser.parse(dateStart, LocalDateTime::from);
    LocalDateTime secondDate = parser.parse(dateStop, LocalDateTime::from);
    return firstDate.until(secondDate, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Note that because you don't have information about the time zone and any daylight-saving transitions that may occur, the results might not match what people expect in every case. You should clarify the use case, and get more information about the zone if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException`, you can use the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class instead of `LocalTime`, since it combines date and time objects, and supports seconds (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-). Since you want to get the absolute difference between both `LocalDateTime` objects, you can insert the `secondDateTime` first and the `firstDateTime` second into the `Duration.between(...)` method.

```
public static long dateTimeDiffInMinutes(String dateTimeStop, String dateTimeStart) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime firstDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStart, formatter);
        LocalDateTime secondDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStop, formatter);
        Duration d = Duration.between(secondDateTime,firstDateTime);
        long min = d.toMinutes();

        return min;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the exception while trying to get time difference between two dates, to overcome this issue I converted LocalDate to LocalDateTime

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        
LocalDateTime firstDate = LocalDate.parse(firstDateString,formatter).atStartOfDay();
    
LocalDateTime secondDate = LocalDate.parse(secondDateString,formatter).atStartOfDay();
    
ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(secondDateString,firstDateString);
```